# Batch File, Move and Rename

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have a folder on my desktop which contains five sub folders, each of these sub folders holds about 1000 Pdf files. All of which have a 6 digit name (e.g 567788.pdf).

I would like to copy all the files to another folder and if they have the same name, instead of overwriting the file, I would like it to add something to the name if it is a duplicate.

e.g 567788.pdf -> 567788 (1).pdf

Could this be done using a batch file?

Comment: Yes, that is feasible. You should loop through your source directory using the `FOR` command. Check the existance using `IF EXIST`. Add a `(1)` suffix to avoid clashes (use `SET /?` to learn about parameter substition). The *Stack Overflow* community is not supposed to write such scripts for you. Try it yourself and report questions, once you encounter stumbling blocks.

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/Batch/comments/394y1w/requestmove_and_rename/

Answer (score 0):

For examlpe, try this:

```
find old_dir -type f |while read f ; do old_name=`basename $f`; if [ ! -e new_dir/$old_name ] ; then cp $f new_dir ; else i=1 ; while true ; do new_name="$old_name ($i)" ; if [ ! -e new_dir/$new_name ] ; then cp $f new_dir/$new_name ; break ; else i=`expr $i + 1` fi; done; fi; done
```

Duplicate filenames will receive suffixes (1), (2) etc.